# Format text as like WhatsApp or stackoverflow (Replace symbols to style as bold, italic, and strikethrough in text)

Tags: javascript, regex, text-formatting

```
*this text is bold*, 
_this text is italic_, 
~this text is strikethrough~. 
~_*this text is bold, italic and strike-through*_~
```

I want these text to be presented as,

```html
<b>this text is bold</b>, 
<i>this text is italic</i>, 
<s>this text is strikethrough</s>. 
<s><i><b>this text is bold, italic and strike-through</b></i></s>
```

I have tried this regex and It works for a combination of symbols (*, _, ~).

```
text
    .replace(/(?:\*)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\*|\n).)+)(?:\*)/g, '<b>$1</b>')
    .replace(/(?:_)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\n|_).)+)(?:_)/g, '<i>$1</i>')
    .replace(/(?:~)(?:(?!\s))((?:(?!\n|~).)+)(?:~)/g, '<s>$1</s>');
```

But as per WhatsApp's rules. It does not work all the time. For example, using some specific characters (`, : ; space _ ~ . \n * _ ~`) at the beginning of the block, it allows the block to be bold/ italic. But using different character will restricts the block from being bold/ italic/ strike-through.

```
*this text is bold* -> <b>this text is bold</b>
,*this text is bold* -> ,<b>this text is bold</b>
@*this text is not bold* -> @*this text is not bold* (Unchanged! will not be bold.)
```

Also, there are some other conditions. Using more than 2 symbols (* _ ~) will restrict the block from being bold/ italic.

```
**this text is bold** -> <b>*this text is bold*</b>
***this text is not bold** -> ***this text is not bold** (unchanged! will not be bold!)
```

I want to handle all those WhatsApp conditions. Can I do this using regex?

Comment: It's called markdown. Use a library for parsing it and converting it into valid html.

Comment: What does "It does not work for combination of symbols" mean? [It looks like it is working for your example](https://ideone.com/JnRDNk)

Comment: A couple moments regarding your attempt: `(?:(?!\n|_).)+` is equivalent to `[^_\n]+`, but way slower. You overusing non-capturing groups for no apparent reason: you regex can be shorten to `/~(?!\s)([^~\n]+)~/g`. Input like this `*_value*_` will result in incorrect HTML. Usually in markdown backslash can be used to escape symbols: input like `\*value\*` will result in output \*value\*, your attempt seems to miss that feature.

Comment: There are some other conditions which need to be taken care of. For example, space should not be at the beginning of a word surrounded by symbols (*, _, ~). Like this one, some other conditions sometimes restricts a word to be bold/ italic/ strike through

Comment: @SayadAhmedShaurov, I am misunderstanding this condition.  If the specifier is immediately preceded by a space, the element tags should not be added?  For example, _'* example*"_.

Comment: Yes, this is a condition of how whatsapp renders any text. There are also some other conditions. Ex: space, comma, full-stop, semicolon and some other characters can be placed at the beginning. But except these specific characters, If any other characters ({,[,?,},] etc.) are put before symbols (star, underscore, ~), the text will not be changed. ([* bold* , unchanged.)
Like this, there are also some edge cases. @Reilas

Comment: @SayadAhmedShaurov, I've updated my answer, to incorporate the initial white-space, and _(?<![\{\[?}\]])_ look-around.

Comment: @SayadAhmedShaurov, please explain what should happen if input is `*_word*_`

Comment: `*_word*_` will result in, `<b>_word</b>_` in whatsapp. @markalex

Comment: @Reilas May be, it could be easier If you only allow characters which do not restrict the behaviour. For ex, these characters (, : ; space _ ~ . \n) do not restrict any word from being bold/ italic.
Ex: `;*bold*` -> `;<b>bold</b>`

Comment: @SayadAhmedShaurov, possibly.  Typically it'd be more logical to check against, despite having to provide every character.  That's why it may actually be easier to just implement a markdown engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following.

Although, if the text contains any of those characters, it will produce an unexpected result.

```js
var string = `
These should pass
  *this text is bold*, 
  _this text is italic_, 
  ~this text is strikethrough~. 
  ~_*this text is bold, italic and strike-through*_~

And, these should fail
  _ example_
  {*example*}
  example*
  example*
`;

string = string.replace(/(?<![{[?}\]])\*(?!\s)(.+?)\*/g, '<b>$1</b>');
string = string.replace(/(?<![{[?}\]])_(?!\s)(.+?)_/g, '<i>$1</i>');
string = string.replace(/(?<![{[?}\]])~(?!\s)(.+?)~/g, '<s>$1</s>');

console.log(string);
```

Comment: A couple side notes: symbol class doesn't require that much escaping inside, `[?{}[\]]` is fine. `(?!\s)(.+?)` is equivalent to `(\S.*?)`, but latter will have better performance.